# Sending a `Reader` between two functions

Tags: io, go

I'm trying to make a `GET` request and then send the content I get to another site in a `POST` request. The following code works fine:

```
func deliver(sourceURL *url.URL, destinationURL *url.URL) {
    client := &http.Client{}
    sourceResponse, err := http.Get(sourceURL.String())
    if err == nil {
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(sourceResponse.Body)
        client.Post(destinationURL.String(), "text/html", strings.NewReader(string(body)))
    }
}
```

But this reads the entire response into memory - how to I stream the response into the POST request instead? Here's what I'm trying:

```
func deliver(sourceURL *url.URL, destinationURL *url.URL) {
    client := &http.Client{}
    sourceResponse, err := http.Get(sourceURL.String())
    if err == nil {
        client.Post(destinationURL.String(), "text/html", sourceResponse.Body)
    }
}
```

I'd assume this would work, but it sends only an empty request (no body). Why is this? Doesn't the `client.Post` function actually attempt to read the response?

Here's an example on the Go playground: http://play.golang.org/p/_EO80aj6wr
Sending the `dataReader` instead of `sourceResponse.Body` works perfectly, but sending the `sourceResponse.Body` directly doesn't work.

Example Links:

```
http://localhost:3000/fetch?dest=http://requestb.in/177ji621&src=http://www.google.com
http://requestb.in/177ji621?inspect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a little test program to try this out

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

var client = &http.Client{}

func httpd() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Printf("%s Request from %s", r.Method, r.RemoteAddr)
        if r.Method == "GET" {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Here is a GET body")
            return
        }
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("body read failed: %v", err)
        }
        log.Printf("Body received from %s: %q", r.Method, body)
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func deliver(sourceURL *url.URL, destinationURL *url.URL) {
    sourceResponse, err := http.Get(sourceURL.String())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("post failed: %v", err)
    }
    postResponse, err := client.Post(destinationURL.String(), "text/html", sourceResponse.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("post failed: %v", err)
    }
    postResponse.Body.Close()
    sourceResponse.Body.Close()
}

func main() {
    go httpd()
    src, err := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:8080/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("src parse failed: %v", err)
    }
    dst, err := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:8080/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("dst parse failed: %v", err)
    }
    deliver(src, dst)
}
```

It worked fine, producing this output

```
2014/10/04 08:40:26 GET Request from 127.0.0.1:48910
2014/10/04 08:40:26 POST Request from 127.0.0.1:48911
2014/10/04 08:40:26 Body received from POST: "Here is a GET body"
```

So the problem with your code will probably be revealed by the errors you aren't checking - the one in the Post most likely.

Also note that you want to re-use `http.Client` if you can, so you can get connection pooling.

---

**Update** after reviewing update to question.

I tried my test program with `http://requestb.in/` and it doesn't show the body.  However I do see this `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` so my suspicion is that `requestb.in` doesn't support chunked transfer encoding.

If you provide the entire body to the request then go sets the `Content-Length` header, however [if you provide a stream](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Write) then go uses [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).  Even though chunked transfer encoding is a non optional part of the HTTP/1.1 spec there are quite a few servers which don't support it properly.

Comment: No idea why it isn't work for me. Tried checking for all errors, but no issues there. I can confirm that the request is being sent, but the body is still empty.

Comment: If you want more help, then post a working example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I've added a Go playground example up in the question - looks like I can reproduce clearly.

Comment: Sort of, in the sense that I'm guessing that's probably the problem. But I still had the same issues on a Go test itself. If you're still curious the code is up here: https://github.com/sudhirj/monolith in `fetch.go` and `fetch_test.go`.